# Python HTTP Session RelayRides.com

Tags: php, python, http, session

I have researched many python post and sites to build a few other scripts that log into specific accounts of mine to scrape/parse data from a site.  I have come across one I cannot figure out, relayrides.com.  The site uses PHP and I have successfully logged into other php based pages using python, but it seems a JSESSIONID and rr_u_cid are set when the pages loads and passed with the POST from, see sample code used to login to other pages:

```
`payload = {
'action': '/login',
'email': 'user@gmail.com',
'password': 'pass1234'
}

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36'
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://relayrides.com/login', data=payload)
    response = c.get('https://relayrides.com/earnings', headers=headers)
print(response.text)`
```

I've tried pass the settings a cookie in the header, using CookiJar, etc.  I am just new to python and web-scraping with python.

Thanks,

dickie

Comment: Try logging in through Firefox or Chrome with your console open on the network tab and see what the post request is like.

Comment: Yeah, I have used both firefox and chrome to inspect the POST request.  I see the sessionid and rr_u_cid I mention, username, pw, and three other blank ids.  I have tried adding these to the payload above and the headers, but nothing.

Comment: Maybe it's checking for something else like a referrer header? In Firefox you can right click the request in the network tab and **copy as curl**. Try running that from your command line and see if it returns what you expect.